# How to associate a model through another model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

For my rails4/angular app I have a movie model, and a trailer model. When I create a movie record, I also create one or more trailer records. I would like to create a json response where the movies trailers are included in each movie.

So I need to create some kind of association between the two models.

A trailer will only belong to one movie, but a movie can have many trailers. So in my trailer model I have,

```
belongs_to :movie
```

And in my movie model I have,

```
has_many :trailers
```

The create function in my trailer controller,

```
def create
  trailer = Trailer.create(trailer_params)
  redirect_to :root 
end
```

And the create function in my movie controller,

```
def create

   @movie = Movie.find_or_create_by movie_params
   current_user.movies << @movie
   redirect_to :root
   current_user.followers.each { |follower| @movie.create_activity(key: 'movie.create', owner: current_user, recipient: follower) }
end
```

And in my movie controller I have this index,

```
def index
  @movie = Movie.all
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json do
      render :json => @movie.to_json(include: :trailers)
    end
  end
end
```

The output of the json render is like this,

```
{  
  "id":7,
  "title":"The Revenant",
  "release_date":"2016-01-28",
  "image":"/oXUWEc5i3wYyFnL1Ycu8ppxxPvs.jpg",
  "movie_id":"281957",
  "backdrop":"/kiWvoV78Cc3fUwkOHKzyBgVdrDD.jpg",
  "trailers":[  

  ]
}
```

Is there a way I can associate the trailers with the movies so I can include them into the movies?

*** updated ***

I have a button in a template with an ng-click,

```
.addmovie{"ng-click" => "addMovie(movie)"}
```

Which calls the `addMovie` function in my angular controller,

In this function I run through several angular services to get my data, but this is the function that creates the trailers,

```
movieAdd.trailer(movie.id)
.then(function(response){
  $scope.youtubeTrailer = [];

  angular.forEach(response.results, function(item){
    $scope.youtubeTrailer = [];
    $scope.youtubeTrailer.push(item.key);
    var youtubeLink = $scope.youtubeTrailer.toString();
    createTrailer.create({
      link:     youtubeLink,
      movie_id: $scope.movieListID.id
    }).then(init);

  })
```

Comment: Looks like that 's already happening since you have a "trailers" array in the movie JSON. what else are you looking for?

Comment: The trailer array is comming from the `render :json => @movie.to_json(include: :trailers)` but the arrays are empty. Even though there are movies and trailers in the database. There's no association between a trailer and a movie when the trailers are created.

Comment: While creating trailer you have to pass for which movie you want to add trailer. You can give a select box with movies list and can pass `movie_id` in the same form of trailer.

Comment: you can use `gem 'active_model_serializers'`, [screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/409-active-model-serializers)

Comment: @OlegSobchuk I do still need to make an association between movies and trailers though.

Comment: @PardeepDhingra could you perhaps give an example of your suggestion? I find it very abstract.

Comment: `active_model_serializers` will help you. It helps to build very useful JSON in easy way

Comment: @PeterBoomsma share your trailers form, i will  update code in that.

Comment: @PardeepDhingra I'm not sure what you mean with `trailers form`, but I've added the function in my angular controller where I create the trailers.

Comment: @OlegSobchuk does `active_model_serializers` create associations between models?

Comment: Are your routes nested?  `resources :movies do; resources :trailers; end` ... if so, then the `movie_id` key should be in your params, so in your trailer create you can do `movie = Movie.find(params[:movie_id])` and then in your next line `trailer = movie.trailers.create(trailer_params)`

Comment: @SteveTurczyn I keep getting the error `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Movie with 'id'=106646):
  app/controllers/trailers_controller.rb:13:in `create' do you know why it's looking for `id` and not `movie_id` ?
`

Comment: Because the field IS called `id` in the movies table... the same field is called `movie_id` in the params.  That's normal. This is an interesting error, as you have a value "106646" but for some reason the Movie object with that id doesn't exist.

Comment: @SteveTurczyn The value `106646` is just a value of the string `movie_id`. And not the id of the actual record.